# Transformation issue with SVG to GeoJSON conversion

Tags: qgis, openlayers, geojson, svg

I have a vector image in SVG format. (without georeferences)

[image: example1]

I am trying to display it using OpenLayers to display properties of different polygons in it.

I tried converting it to GeoJSON but the resulting render appears to be stretched (ratios are not preserved).

Is there a transformation or a map projection that I am missing or recreating a GeoJSON from scratch the only relevant choice?

[image: example2]